# angularjs custom directive conditional templateUrl via attribute

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am trying to load conditional template urls via attributes, my directives is as follows.

The directive is in a ng-repeate and when box.key == 'experiences' the expression is returning education-form.php and not experiences-form.php.

```
<div multiple-form
   directive-data='directiveData'
   template-url="box.key == 'experiences'? 'experiences-form.php':'education-form.php'"
   item="item"
   forms="forms"
   form-name="{{box.key}}{{item._id}}"
   onsave="updateMultipleUser(box.key, item._id, $data)"
   onreset="formAction($formName, 'reset')"
   cancel="formAction($formName, 'cancel')"
   >
</div>
```

Directive DDO

```
 {
     restrict: 'A',
     replace: true,
     scope: {
         directiveData: '=',
         onsave: '&',
         onreset: '&',
         cancel: '&',
         formName: '@',
         forms: '=',
         item: '='
     },
     controller: controller,
     templateUrl: function(tElement, tAttrs) {
         return $rootScope.$eval(tAttrs.templateUrl);
     }
 }
```

attempting using link function

```
<div multiple-form
   directive-data='directiveData'
   template-map="{
   experiences:'experiences-form.php',
   courses:'education-form.php'
   }"
   box="box" 
   item="item"
   forms="forms"
   form-name="{{box.key}}{{item._id}}"
   onsave="updateMultipleUser(box.key, item._id, $data)"
   onreset="formAction($formName, 'reset')"
   cancel="formAction($formName, 'cancel')"
   >
</div>

 controller: controller,
     link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
         // shows correct template url ... now what?
         console.log(scope.templateMap[scope.box.key]);
     },
     templateUrl: function(tElement, tAttrs) {
         return 'experiences-form.php';
     }
```

Comment: When you use scope.eval property has to be on the scope or inherited from its parent. rootScope has no idea what is `box.key`

Comment: how to pass scope to  templateUrl? sorry angular newbie here ;)

Comment: The thing is you cant.. :( it is too early in the directive compilation phase to have access to the scope. But you could try one thing, if this is the only one on the page. `angular.element(document.querySelector("[multiple-form]")).scope().$eval(tAttrs.templateUrl)` i have never tried it.

Comment: You can have static string in the attributes which you can directly access

Comment: @PSL other way would be add template from the directive link function instead of from `templateUrl`

Comment: @pankajparkar Yeah but that is an obvious way though.. :) append the element and re-compile

Comment: @PSL I will try and implement your solution and post back

Comment: @pankajparkar could you please provide a simple example with link function?

Comment: @ericsicons look at my edit in answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Markup**

```
<div multiple-form
   directive-data='directiveData'
   ng-attr-template-url="{{box.key == 'experiences'? 'experiences-form.php':'education-form.php'}}"
   item="item"
   forms="forms"
   form-name="{{box.key}}{{item._id}}"
   onsave="updateMultipleUser(box.key, item._id, $data)"
   onreset="formAction($formName, 'reset')"
   cancel="formAction($formName, 'cancel')"
   >
</div>
```

Then your templateUrl function would be

```
 templateUrl: function(tElement, tAttrs) {
     $timeout(function(){ //wait until the ng-attr evaluates a value.
         return tAttrs.templateUrl;
     })
 }
```

Not sure it will work or not.

**Update**

Another obivious way would be loading template from the link function and append it from there it self rather than having call template through `templateUrl`

**HTML**

```
<div multiple-form
   directive-data='directiveData'
   template-path="{{box.key == 'experiences'? 'experiences-form.php':'education-form.php'}}"
   item="item"
   forms="forms"
   form-name="{{box.key}}{{item._id}}"
   onsave="updateMultipleUser(box.key, item._id, $data)"
   onreset="formAction($formName, 'reset')"
   cancel="formAction($formName, 'cancel')">
</div>
```

**Directive**

```
 {
     restrict: 'A',
     replace: true,
     scope: {
         directiveData: '=',
         onsave: '&',
         onreset: '&',
         cancel: '&',
         formName: '@',
         forms: '=',
         item: '=',
         templatePath: '@'
     },
     controller: controller,
     link: function(scope, element, attrs){
         //here you will have template path in your scope.templatePath variable
         //you can load template using it.
         var template = getTemplate(); //this can be done by below mentioned way
         element.append($compile(template)(scope));//addding compiled element
     }
 }
```

Inside your link function you could append directive template by loading template on demand, there are several way to load template from directive

### Using $templateCache

While using `$templateCache` you need to put that template in angular `$templateCache` at the run phase,

```
app.run(function($templateCache){
   $templateCache.put('myTemplate.html', '<div>myTemplate</div>')
})
```

After doing this you could eaisily access that template in directive just by adding `$templateCache.get('myTemplate.html')`

Another way of adding template in `$templateCache` would be using `script` tag with `type="text/ng-template"`

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="myTemplate.html">
  <div>myTemplate</div>
</script>
```

### Using $http.get

You could do get the template by using `$http.get('myTemplate.html')` in success of it you will get data that is nothing but html content that file. You could compile and append that html to your directive element.

### Using ng-include

You could use ng-include directive here. You need to do create a dummy div that will have an ng-include directive with desired `template-path` like `<div ng-include="templatePath"></div>`,it will load a template in that div. If you don't want to use div then you could use `<ng-include src="templatePath"></ng-include>`. But this is not much preferable way of doing code. because it does create child scope like ng-repeat does.

Comment: @PSL I just thought about it..sorry for my bad idea..what will it consider for `templateUrl` or will it throw an error?

Comment: i guess it might throw error as you dont return a template. It does not even take a promise, which would have been awesome if it was able to

Comment: @pankajparkar thanks but how can the template be loaded at this stage?

Comment: one way way would be using `$templateCache.get('templateName')` but before using it you need to put your template in angular `$templateCache` using angular `$templateCache.put('templateName', 'template')` while running run block, other way would be use `$http.get('test.html')` in success of it you will get content of it

Comment: & then the append it do directive element something like `element.append($compile(ajaxContent)(scope))`

Comment: Thanks!! Finally it worked in my case    var template = $templateCache.get(scope.templateMap[scope.box.key]); 
                   element.append($compile(template)(scope)); since I have all the templates in script tags at startup

Comment: @ericsicons see all those possibility I covered in my answer..Glad to help you...Thanks :)