# passing value from parent directive to child directive's template function

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angularjs-model

I'm trying to access value that is passed from the parent's directive on the child directive's template function.

Please refer to the below plunker.

[Plunker Link](https://plnkr.co/edit/qjEmuwr2Z9k4ZsywBaIH?p=preview)

CODE:

Parent Directive:

```
directive('parentDir', function(){
  return {
    controller: ['$scope',function($scope){
      $scope.myVal = 'HELLO';
    }],
    templateUrl: 'parentDir.html'
  }
})
```

Child Directive:

```
directive('childDir', function(){
  return {
    template: function(element,attrs){
      alert(attrs.val);
    }
  }
})
```

parentDir.html:

```
<div>
  <child-dir val="{{myVal}}"></child-dir>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add the `val` attribute to the directive like this:

```
.directive('childDir', function(){
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope : {
      val : '='
    },
    link : function(scope, element, attrs) {
      return alert(scope.val);
    }
  }
})
```

Here is a working [plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/OTny8L0RfTnhLhYdhIuW?p=preview)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. but I want the value on the template function not on the link function.

Comment: Hmm I'm not very familiar with the template function. Did you already came across this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30704757/angular-access-scope-from-directive-template-function) ?